# libcurl http auth on site

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I use libcurl for auth in site. I make it with many functions, for example:

```
char *CheckLoginPass(char *login, char *pass)
{
  //use curl_easy_setopt for check login/pass
  return stdout;
} 

char *AuthOnSite() //make auth on site
{
  //use curl_easy_setopt for auth by login/pass
  return htmlpage;
}

char *TestMyAuth()
{
  //use curl_easy_setopt for test auth
  return htmlpage;
}

void Test()
{
  char *stdout = CheckLoginPass("login", "pass"); // is good
  char *htmlpage = AuthOnSite(); // is good
  htmlpage = TestMyAuth(); // session is lose and I am not logined on site
}
```

What me do to avoid dropping session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to configure a "cookie jar" for libcurl to store its session cookie in, see: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.html and refer to that when you make the TestMyAuth call, see: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE.html